# Help solving $\int_0^\infty\!\!\frac{\log\left(x\right)}{\left(x+a\right)^3}{\scriptsize dx}$ for $a>0$

Tags: complex-analysis

$$
\mbox{Consider}\quad
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\log\left(x\right) \over \left(\, x + a\,\right)^3}
\,\mathrm{d}x\quad
\mbox{where}\ a\ \mbox{is}\ positive.
$$

- First, we make a branch cut along the negative imaginary axis, and then consider the standard contour with a small semicircle around 0 and a small semicircle centered at $-a$.
- Letting $\,\mathrm{f}\left(z\right)$ be the integrand above with $z$ in place of $x$, the residue at $-a$ is $-1/\left(2a^{2}\right)$.
- I'm able to show that the integral around the big semicircle goes to 0 as the radius goes to infinity and similarly with the arc around 0 as the radius goes to 0, but there's a little trouble with the one around $-a$.
- If $-a$ were a simple pole, then it would just evaluate to $-\pi\mathrm{i}$ times the residue, but I have an order $3$ pole.

Any suggestions ?. I was also thinking of rotating the standard contour by $\pi/2$ so that the pole is inside the contour rather than outside.

Comment: @Vlad I understand that your edits to the title make it look better and improves readability, but your edits actually take up too much [front page space](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730/290074).

Comment: Why not integrate by part? Aside from dealing with the two limits carefully, the integral is elementary.

Comment: @IrregularUser Sorry, I assumed we accidentally edited it simultaneously.

Comment: @Vlad No problem, nothing to worry about :)

Comment: Can we use integration by parts to find the antiderivative to be $-\frac{\log(x)}{2(x+a)^2} + \frac{1}{2a^2}\big(\log(x)-\log(x+a)\big) + \frac{1}{2a(x+a)}$ and then take the limit as $x\to0$ and $x\to\infty$ to get the result $\frac{1 - \log(a)}{2a^2}$.

Comment: @Hoang-NganNguyen. I suspect that the result is $\frac{ \log(a)-1}{2a^2}$ provided that $a>0$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici. You are right!

Comment: @Hoang-NganNguyen Yes of course, I'll work it out right now; I always seem to forget the elementary approaches when studying for quals. Thanks

Comment: If you want to integrate with the branch-cut along the '$\color{#f00}{negative\ axis}$'  you have to evaluate
$$
\int_{C}{\ln^{2}\left(z\right) \over \left(z \color{#f00}{-} a\right)^{3}}\,\mathrm{d}z
$$
The whole procedure becomes similar to the fine Marko Riedel answer. Note the $\color{#f00}{-}$ symbol. Don't worry. Later on, you'll have to change $x \mapsto -x$ along the way and you'll recover the factor $+$ since $x - a \mapsto -x - a = -\left(x + a\right)$. $\color{#f00}{\large Do\ it}$. It's a good exercise.

Comment: @Felix Marin, I'll definitely try that; this was a question on a complex analysis qual, so I'm sure that's what they're looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose we seek to evaluate

$$K = \int_0^\infty \frac{\log x}{(x+a)^3} \; dx$$

with $a$ positive.

We use $$f(z) = \frac{(\log z)^2}{(z+a)^3}$$

and  integrate around a  keyhole contour  with the  branch cut  of the
logarithm on the positive real  axis and the argument between zero and
$2\pi.$

We obtain

$$2\pi i \mathrm{Res}_{z=-a} f(z)
\\ = \int_0^\infty \frac{(\log z)^2}{(z+a)^3} dz
- \int_0^\infty \frac{(\log z +2\pi i)^2}{(z+a)^3} dz
\\ = -4\pi i \int_0^\infty \frac{\log z}{(z+a)^3} dz
+ 4\pi^2 \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(z+a)^3} dz.$$

The simple one yields

$$\left[-\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{(x+a)^2}\right]_0^\infty
= \frac{1}{2a^2}.$$

Now for the residue we get

$$\frac{1}{2}\left.\left((\log z)^2\right)''\right|_{z=-a}
= \left.\left(\frac{1}{z} \log z\right)'\right|_{z=-a} 
= \left.\left(\frac{1}{z^2} - \frac{1}{z^2} \log z\right)\right|_{z=-a} 
\\ = \frac{1}{a^2} (1-\log a - i\pi).$$

We thus have

$$ \frac{2\pi i}{a^2} (1-\log a - i\pi)
= -4\pi i K + \frac{2\pi^2}{a^2}$$

or

$$ \frac{2\pi i}{a^2} (1-\log a)
= -4\pi i K $$

and finally

$$K = \frac{1}{2a^2} (\log a - 1).$$

This can also be obtained comparing real and imaginary parts of the 
initial integral of $f(z).$

**Remark.** To be rigorous we need to apply ML to the circular components.
We get for the large circle that with $z=R\exp(i\theta)$
$$|\log^2 z| = |\log z|^2 = \sqrt{\log^2 R + \theta^2}^2$$

and hence

$$\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty} 2\pi R
\times \frac{\log^2 R + 4\pi^2}{(R-a)^3} = 0$$

and

$$\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} 2\pi \epsilon
\times \frac{\log^2 \epsilon + 4\pi^2}{(a-\epsilon)^3} = 0.$$

Comment: Thanks, this method seemed to work much nicer than some of the other ones. Would you say moving up a power of $\log$ only helps when you have a real pole? If the pole were not real, then we could take an arc from $R$ to $-R$ and an arc around 0, then look at a the integral on the positive/negative axis and solve for the positive one. Since the pole isn't real, no extra arc around it would be necessary.

Comment: There is no arc around the pole, just a plain keyhole contour aligned with the positive real axis and the pole inside the keyhole in the left half plane.

Comment: I know, I think I just phrased my question/explanation poorly. I think it just goes back to missing the intuition behind you knew to do the keyhole contour versus, say, a semi circle in the half plane with a semicircle on the negative real axis around $-a$ and a semicircle around 0.